# Authorize.net Accept Hosted Form Runs unusual with Iframe

Tags: html, iframe, authorize.net

I am using Authorize.net to post my token and get the payment form in an iframe.
The problem is that a form post to '_self' loads the form correctly while loading the payment form to an i-frame gives me a weird looking form.

This is giving me the a weird looking form page:

```
<iframe id="load_pay" name="load_pay" width="750" height="900" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<form method="post" target="load_pay" action="https://test.authorize.net/payment/payment">
```

This is giving me a normal post:

```
<form method="post" target="_self" action="https://test.authorize.net/payment/payment">
```

Here are the screenshots for both of them:

ErrorImage with Iframe:
[image]

Normal Image without Iframe:
[image]

Could it be internet explorer settings issue?
What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One solution that worked for me was to turn off compatibility view in IE.